# How do you name your variables?

Tags: c++, namespaces, naming-conventions

Is google C++ style guide ( http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.xml ) good in your opinion? I am following that doc, because i *needed* a guide!! Otherwise, i would change my naming convention everyday...

Another question: when developing a software library, all of us probably will put all the stuff in one or more namespace(s). Suppose your library is called MyLib and suppose you have a class called CMemory. As you can see, CMemory is a common name and it could generate an ambiguity when the library is used, even if CMemory is under the namespace MyLib. Usually, do you use some prefix for classes, and other objects accessible with `MyLib::` (for example: mlCMemory)?

Comment: @Avakar I voted for it to be "Not constructive". "in your opinion" will lead to debate

Answer (score 3):

I think that many people wouldn't consider the google c++ rules to be what they would use for writing c++ code in general, for example "We do not use C++ exceptions." is not something the majority would likely agree with.

As for the variable naming rules, they seem as good as any. It doesn't really matter as long as you have some consistant rule.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Google's naming convention seems fine.

> As you can see, CMemory is a common name and it could generate an
>   ambiguity when the library is used, even if CMemory is under the
>   namespace MyLib. Usually, do you use some prefix for classes, and
>   other objects accessible with MyLib:: (for example: mlCMemory)?

No prefix. What would be the point of namespaces if you assume they don't do their job.

Note that Hungarian Notation (classnames begin with C) doesn't add much, and Google doesn't seem to be using it either.

Answer (score 0):

> Is google C++ style guide good in your opinion?

i read it a few years ago, and disagreed with a number of things, and preferred other styles and idioms.

**Naming**

personally, i use `t_` for classes and UpperCamel for namespaces:

```
namespace MonLibrary {
  class t_basic_object;
}
```

as well as the prefix `d_` for member variables. but that description leaves out many other conventions i use.